# What is the REST Web Api 2 means of purging an entire table?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

A fundamental concept in RESTful web services is the resource, such as `api/delete/{id}`.

However, my goal is to purge all records from a table and reload the table through Web Api 2 web services *(hopefully without violating too many RESTful principles)*.

I do not want to do a `GET` to retrieve the records then send a `DELETE` request for each resource. I am attempting to send a mass delete or truncate request without specifying any specific resources or incurring the cost of `GET`ting all the resources to turn around and send them back through their own individual `DELETE` request. Or is this the right way to do it?

Is there a way to do so? Or would I `POST` a delete request instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would seem to be to use an HTTP `DELETE` request on the resource itself (as opposed to on each item in the resource). So your action would be:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteAllItems()
```

Comment: I am currently attempting this, however I keep getting an error because the HTTP request looks like a `GET` for some reason, even though I am explicitly stating the method of `[HttpDelete]`

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the way your client is constructing the request rather than an issue with your API.

Comment: Here's what the construction looks like

        `[Route("delete")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public IHttpActionResult Delete()`

So the end result is `/api/controller/delete` but it comes back as a `GET` error. However that's a side issue I will look at. You have provided a response to the original question though. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. As a RESTful service though it should be resource-based. An endpoint of `api/controller/delete` specifies an action and is thus not strictly RESTful. Your endpoint should be `api/controller/` with the HTTP verb specifying the action that is performed on it. Hence you can have a `GET` request to return all items within the resource and `DELETE` to remove them all. So your route attribute should be `[Route("")]` with another `[HttpDelete]` attribute specifying the action.

Comment: If it's coming in looking like a "GET" it's likely because that's what your client/browser is sending it as and that's where the problem lies and not with the web api code

Comment: @Matti Price Yes I pulled up Fiddler and specifically used `DELETE` as the HTTP Verb and it works.

Comment: @strickt01 Ah yes, I am specifying an action and that is a bad practice. I will correct that. 

_Your endpoint should be api/controller/ with the HTTP verb specifying the action that is performed on it_  < Your response makes sense here. I will fix this. Thank you!

Comment: If you're happy with it could you accept my answer then please?